# Displaying a color composite using GEE python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I want to display an color composite image from my image collection:

```
listOfImages = dataset_fxm.toList(dataset_fxm.size())

firstImage = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(0))

Map.addLayer(firstImage,{band:['B5','B4','B3']},"patan")
```

But the following error is showing up: `name 'band' is not defined`.

And I have also used **'bands'** for defining the bands, but still the same error.

I am running the task on jupyter notebook python API GEE.

Answer (score 0):

It is the whole code? If yes, there are some stuff missing: You have to define the image collection and visualization parameter. Take a look at this question: [Google Earth Engine - get true color (RGB) of Landsat 8 SR](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300065/google-earth-engine-get-true-color-rgb-of-landsat-8-sr) There is a complete snippet for Landsat 8 you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I think that GEE generally takes 'Bands' as a parameter and not 'band'.
For example in term of visualisation, you would write :

Map.addLayer(firstImage, {bands:['B5','B4','B3']}, "patan")